# How to temporarily hide UIPopoverController

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios, drag-and-drop, uipopovercontroller

I have a `UIPopoverController` which i want to drag items from it and drop them on another view.
I implemented the mechanism for Drag & Drop from a popover but i want it to be even better: while you dragging, i think the popover should be hidden so you could drop items right underneath it.

Since `UIPopoverController` is not a "Classic" view controller i dont know how to hide it temporarily without dismissing it irreversibly.

BUT since `UIPopoverController` presents something on the screen, there got to be a "View" somewhere inside that popover controller that i can hide and show...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it work to "hold into" the view controller in the popover in some way (like an ivar of the object that presents the popover) and then just dismiss the popover?  That way, the view controller will still be there and when you want to show it again, you can.

Comment: I Actually thought about that, but it dosen't seem right in my current application architecture. Anyway, in the end i'm creating my own "Popover" class because i'm gonna be using it a lot.